# Add dynamic 45 degree line to ggplot scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to create an additional line to a ggplot graph, which is dynamically adjusted to the scales of the values displayed. I would like to add this line in order to quickly see if one of the categories consistently is larger than the other one.
Therefore, it would be great if I could add the line to each plot independent of the level.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  test <- structure(list(Date = c("202107", "202106", "202104", "202102", 
            "202101", "202105", "202103"), Val1 = c(199165942214.504, 200405660266.164, 
             194931793612.389, 187140775347.389, 186193256330.389, 196323803492.389, 
             191885428112.389), Val2 = c(194546158558, 195351933631, 188748709692, 
             181522458543, 180653727026, 190427709692, 186599848808)), row.names = c(NA, 
             -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
      
  test %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Val1, y = Val2)) + 
  geom_point()
  
  # Not working, because of the wrong intercept.
  test %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Val1, y = Val2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, size = 0.5)
```

Solutions as proposed in this answer, obviously won't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182543/5795592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the issue is. It draws a 45 degree line in data space. If you want it to be 45 degrees in graphic space, you need to set the coordinates such that 1 unit on the x-axis is of equal length to 1 unit on the y-axis.

This seems correct:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
test <- structure(list(
  Date = c("202107", "202106", "202104", "202102", 
           "202101", "202105", "202103"), 
  Val1 = c(199165942214.504, 200405660266.164, 
           194931793612.389, 187140775347.389, 186193256330.389, 196323803492.389, 
           191885428112.389), 
  Val2 = c(194546158558, 195351933631, 188748709692, 
           181522458543, 180653727026, 190427709692, 186599848808)
  ), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
  
p <- test %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=Val1, y = Val2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, size = 0.5)
p
```

[image]

We can show that the intercept is correct by expanding the limits to include the origin:

```r
p + xlim(c(0, NA)) + ylim(c(0, NA))
```

[image]

To have data space correspond to graphics space, you can set equal coordinates.

```r
p + coord_equal()
```

[image]

Finally, you can harmonize the x scale and y scale limits the show the same range:

```r
p + xlim(range(test$Val1, test$Val2)) + ylim(range(test$Val1, test$Val2)) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. Of course the line with Intercept at 0 is correct, but I am interested in what you define as 45 degree in the graphics space.